# Need logic for joining two tables and using distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to work with the below 2 tables and get the last table as my output. Any help would be great.

Table 1 :

```
Type     Code   Current  BPO    Forecast
NULL     NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL
         NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
                NULL    NULL    NULL
A        NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
A               NULL    NULL    NULL
A        A001   55      32      56.322
A        A002   NULL    NULL    NULL
A        A003   66.22   44.21   81.13
A        A004   NULL    NULL    NULL
A        B001   NULL    NULL    NULL
A        B002   NULL    NULL    NULL
R        A001   29.423  53.245  82.444
R        A003   100     100      100
R        A004   NULL    NULL    NULL
R        A023   NULL    NULL    NULL
R        C001   89.333  23.66   100
S        A001   22.21   71.1    38.45
S        C001   67      34      62
S               NULL    NULL    NULL
Z        A003   12      22.1    90.42
Z        B001   56      43.332  80.33
Z        A023   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Table 2 :

```
Index Type   Code
Bact    A   A001
Bact    R   A001
Bact    Z   B001
Bact    S   C001
Dis1    A   A001
Dis1    A   A002
Dis1    A   A003
Dis1    R   C001
Dis1    Z   A023
MEX     A   A004
MEX     A   B001
MEX     R   A001
MEX     S   A001
MEX     A   B002
TED     R   A003
TED     R   A004
TED     S   A001
TED     Z   A003
ZES     R   A023
ZES     Z   A003
ZES     Z   A023
ZES     Z   B001
```

I need the below columns as my output :

```
Index    Current    BPO Forecast
Bact  (Avg of A A001,A B001,A C001,R A001,R B001,R C001,S A001,S B001,S C001,Z A001,Z B001,Z C001)
Dis1
MEX
TED
ZES
```

Here Current , BPO and Forecast should be average of the combination of Type and Code for a particular Index.
We are also eliminating all the rows which do not match with the Table 2. I am also putting Null values in Table 1 combination as these were the actual values in my table

Also below are my scripts :

Table 1 Create and Insert Scripts :-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
[Type] [char](1) NULL,
[Code] [varchar](5) NULL,
[Current] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
[BPO] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
[Forecast] [decimal](18, 8) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES(NULL,'',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('','',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A','',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A','A001',55.00000000,32.00000000,56.32200000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A','A002',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A','A003',66.22000000,44.21000000,81.13000000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A','A004',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A','B001',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('A','B002',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('R','A001',28.42300000,53.24500000,82.44400000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('R','A003',100.00000000,100.00000000,100.00000000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('R','A004',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('R','A023',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('R','C001',89.34440000,52.43200000,100.00000000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('S','A001',22.22000000,18.32200000,65.00000000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('S','C001',67.00000000,34.00000000,62.00000000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('S','',NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('Z','A003',12.00000000,22.56000000,38.43000000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('Z','B001',56.00000000,43.23300000,81.69000000)
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Type],[Code],[Current],[BPO],[Forecast])VALUES('Z','A023',NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Table 2 Create and Insert Scripts :-

```
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Bact','A','A001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Bact','R','A001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Bact','Z','B001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Bact','S','C001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Dis 1','A','A001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Dis 1','A','A002')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Dis 1','A','A003')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Dis 1','R','C001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('Dis 1','Z','A023')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('MEX','A','A004')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('MEX','A','B001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('MEX','R','A001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('MEX','S','A001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('MEX','A','B002')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('TED','R','A003')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('TED','R','A004')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('TED','S','A001')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('TED','Z','A003')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('ZES','R','A023')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('ZES','Z','A003')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('ZES','Z','A023')
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Index],[Type],[Code])VALUES('ZES','Z','B001')
```

Comment: You seem to have put a lot of effort into asking a question and providing the resources for someone else to do the work for you. Did you put that much effort into trying to solve it yourself?

Comment: Yes.. I am trying to do the same. Its just that I am in crunch of time and wanted some help. I am also working on it and trying to get a solution simultaneously.

Comment: I would suggest you look up why you should not use EAV tables in a SQL database. YOu wil need to join to this table multiple times, once for each type you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE c_Report CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT [Index] FROM Table4

create table #tempb([Index] varchar(1000), CC decimal(25,6),BPO decimal(25,6),ForeCast decimal(25,6))

DECLARE @Index varchar(1000)

OPEN c_Report
FETCH NEXT FROM c_Report INTO @Index
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    insert into #tempb
    select [Index]
    ,Avg([Current]),Avg(BPO),Avg(ForeCast) from
    (select distinct @Index as [Index],* from
    (Select [Type]
    from Table4
    where [Index]=@Index) a
    ,
    (Select Code
    from Table4
    where [Index]=@Index)b) c
    join Table3 d 
on c.[Type]=d.[Type] and c.Code=d.Code
    group by [Index]
FETCH NEXT FROM c_Report INTO @Index
END
close c_Report
deallocate c_Report
select * from #tempb
```

This was what I was looking for. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution meets your needs

```
select T2.[index],Avg(T1.[Current]) as [Current] ,avg(t1.[bpo]) as bpo,avg(t1.[Forecast]) as [Forecast]
from  Table1 T1
join  Table2 T2
on isnull(T1.[type],'') = t2.[type]
and isnull(t1.code,'') = t2.code
group by T2.[index]
```

Comment: Hi Surendra, If you see the query that you have mentioned.. It is mapping the type of Table1 to Table2 and Code of Table1 to Table2.. But my logic is get all the combinations of Type and Code for a particular Index in Table2 and then map the same combinations in Table1 to get the rows. My final output should be an average for a particular index. I hope this makes sense..

Comment: @user1483122 did you try the query in the first place, then let us know what is the difference from expected result you are getting here. Cannot really help without seeing the results, understanding your requirement is hard, but understanding the expected results vs what you got will be easy.